# Add two list to one list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, class

I'm trying to marge two lists that I created through a class to a new list. I use the `__add__` function.
But it constantly adds the first two indexes and stops.

This is my code:

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__items = []
        self.__top = 0

    def is_Empty(self):
        return self.__top <= 0
        try:
            raise Exception('Stack empty.')
        except Exception as error:
            print(error)

    def __str__(self):
        """Print current stack"""
        if self.is_Empty() == True:
            return "Stack empty"
        else:
            return "Stack is not empty"

    def push(self, item):
        """Push item in stack."""
        self.__items.append(item)
        self.__top += 1

    def pop(self):
        """Remove top of the stack."""
        if self.__top <= 0:
            return self.is_Empty()
        self.__top -= 1
        return self.__items.pop()

    def top(self):
        """Return top of the stack."""
        if self.__top <= 0:
            return self.is_Empty()
        else:
            return self.__items[-1]

    def my_stack(self):
        """Show the current stack"""
        if self.__items == []:
            return self.is_Empty()
        else:
            return f"The current stack is {self.__items}"

    def __add__(self,other):
        """Add two lists together"""
        newlst = []
        for i, j in zip(self.__items, other.__items):
            newlst.append(i+j)
            return newlst

    def __eq__(self, other):
        """Return True if two list is equal else Return False """
        return (self is other) or (self.__items) == (other.__items)
```

for example:

```
stack = Stack()
stack.push(1)
stack.push(2)
stack.push(3)
stack2 = Stack()
stack2.push(4)
stack2.push(5)
stack2.push(6)
```

Now I'm trying to add the two stacks into `stack3`:

```
stack3 = stack + stack2
```

The result I get is this:

```
>>> print(stack3)
[5]
```

My goal is to get `stack3` like this:

```
>>> print(stack3)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code

> ```
>    def __add__(self,other):
>         """Add two lists together"""
>         newlst = []
>         for i, j in zip(self.__items, other.__items):
>             newlst.append(i+j)
>             return newlst
> ```

adds the first  elements of each `.__items` list and returns the result after that.

To add the inner lists one after each other and return as list, this would work:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    """Add two lists together"""
    if isinstance(other,Stack):
        return self.__items + other.__items

    return [] # or self.__items or raise Exception
```

To return a new `Stack`-instance you could do:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    """Add two lists together"""
    if isinstance(other, Stack):
        s = Stack()
        for item in self.__items:
            s.push(item)
        for item in other.__items:
            s.push(item)
         return s
    return [] # or self.__items or raise Exception
```